# Multiple callbacks

Tags: java, callback

I need to call the function with callback.
The method asks the server for answer and returns it to the callback.
But I need to send next request to the server.

How can I re-returns the callback from inner method to main callback?

```
void getListOfRSSItems(final String url, final ResponseListener listener) {
    Requester.send(url, new Requester.RequestResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRequestResponse(HttpResponse response) {
            ArrayList<RSSItem> list = getListFromResponse(response);
            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                Requester.send(list.get(i).link, new Requester.RequestResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRequestResponse(HttpResponse response2) {
                        // add content to rss item
                    }
                });
                list.set(i, // returned rss item);
            }
            listener.onResponse(list);
        }
    });
}
```

and how can I return the rss item to the list and return it over listener?
This doesnt wait to add content code and returns the list of RSSItems without content.

Can you help me?

Thank you

Comment: "This doesn't wait to add content code and returns the list of RSSItems without content."   One of the benefits of a callback based approach is that you don't have to wait for the response in order to return from `getListOfRSSItems`.  Do you mean that you're checking some value after `getListOfRSSItems` returns, and it's not changed?  If so, you may just need to a wait a bit longer for the callback to have been called.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you want this operation to be synchronous/blocking you can have a look at the wait and notify methods which are part of each java Object. At the start of your method you could simply create an empty list.

```
final List<RSSItem> rssItems = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
.... 
  @Override
  public void onRequestResponse(HttpResponse response2) {
  this.myClass.rssItems.add(...); // fill your list

  YourClass.this.rssItems.notify(); // when finished wake blocking thread
}
....
rssItems.wait(5000); // waits until rssItems have been filled or 5s have passed. 
                     // your program should be able to tell the difference.
```

Since rssItems is used by only one thread at the same time you don't need any synchronization.